# ¿Cómo puedo hacer el método estático que valida una fecha?

Tags: java

¿Como puedo crear un método estático que dada una fecha en el formato   “dd/mm/aaaa” nos indique si es una fecha válida o no?

Comment: ¡Bienvenida a SOes!, favor de realizar el [recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y puedas comprender como funciona el sitio. Asimismo, revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y si tienes otras dudas puedes visitar el [Centro de Ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help). Para ayudarte con tu problema [**Incluye solo el código suficiente para permitir a otros reproducir el problema.**](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ¿Bienvenido a stacoverflow español! Generalmente es buen visto de mostrar un poco más esfuerzo (por ejemplo con código) en encontrar una solución al problema. Una buena entrada en el tema de `Java`encuentras [aquí](http://sepwww.stanford.edu/sep/jon/family/jos/oop_es/oop1.htm). Para el uso de SO, recomiendo se recomienda el [recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Puedes hacer une funcion `boolean fechaValida(int dd, int mm, int aaa)` que nos indican si `dd`⊂[1,31], `mm`⊂[1,12] con `if`

Answer (score 2):

```
private static SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

public static boolean esValido(String fecha){
    try {
        Date d = sf.parse(fecha); // tratar de interpretar fecha
        return fecha.equals(sf.format(d)); // comparar fecha interpretada con original
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return false; // fecha no es valido y/o no cumpla con formato
    }
}
```

Hay que comparar la fecha formateada con la cadena original, porque `parse` calcula fechas como `32/01/2000` en una manera que los cambia en una fecha legal (`01/02/2000`).